Why does the (( compound command assign to a variable in this case?
$ test=false
$ echo $test
false
$ ((!test))
((test=false))
$ echo $?
1
$ echo $test
0

Why is test now 0? I dont understand where or why (( is assigning to test or why it prints ((test=false)). This only happens when writing the commands manually on the terminal; when running those same commands as a script test stays on "false".

When I do ((!test)) I get an error: bash: false: unbound variable. Is it possible you did false=0 earlier?

Also note that ((!test)) won't work in a script. You're using history expansion, but history isn't enabled by default in scripts.

@Barmar I can reproduce the same behaviour as OP without false=0. What version are you using? I'm using 5.0.

I tested in bash 5.1.4

Firstly, test and false are also the names of builtins which aren't relevant here, so for the sake of clarity, I'm going to change them to foo and bar
$ foo=bar

$ echo $foo
bar

!foo is history expansion, and the matching command is foo=bar.
$ echo !foo
echo foo=bar
foo=bar

$ ((!foo))
((foo=bar))

$ echo $?
1


The extra line below the command there is a preview of the command that's being run. I'm not sure what the technical term for that is.
History expansion is turned off in scripts.

In an arithmetic context, the string bar is treated as a variable name, but that variable isn't defined, so it's evaluated as 0. Hence foo=0.
$ echo $foo
0


P.S. I have my shell set up to colourize the command I'm typing in (by putting a trailing escape sequence in the PS1 '\[\e[36m\]' with the terminator in the PS0 '\e[m'), and it also happens to colourize the history expansion preview and various other things. Helpful in this case :) but it seems kind of hacky so IDK if I'd recommend it.
